# event not firing in windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

```
public void testUssdResponse()
{
     //modem is connected fine here before returning result
     bool result = smsObject.SendUSSD("*1234#");
     if (result)
     {
          smsObject.NewUSSDReceived += smsObject_NewUSSDReceived;
          smsObject.NewUSSDIndication = true;
     }
}
```

below is the event i am expecting to trigger

```
  public void smsObject_NewUSSDReceived(object sender, mCore.NewUSSDReceivedEventArgs e)
  {
        string message = e.Message.ToString();
        string status = e.Status.ToString();

         if (message == "welcome user")
         {
         }
         else
         {
         }
    }
```

The part i need to see the is the message which is returned from the event but when i apply the breakpoint,i cannot  navigate to the code itself.On timer elapsed am  running the function below testUssd

```
 void tm_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
        timer.Interval = (1000 * 60);
        testUssdResponse();
        timer.Interval = 1000 * 60;
 }
```

Comment: Check your title... is a web services or WINDOWS service...?

Comment: Could it be that the event is fired *before* you assign to it?

Comment: @shay__ that's where am stuck.I hope that is the issue.Maybe you can give a solution

Comment: If that's really the issue, all you have to do is to assign to the event (smsObject.NewUSSDReceived += smsObject_NewUSSDReceived) BEFORE you call the method which causes it (smsObject.SendUSSD("*1234#");).